# Is it possible to disable the contextmenu plugin in CKEditor without having to disable any other plugins?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to enable native spellchecking in CKEditor which requires you to disable the CKEditor context menu, however to do that it seems you also need to disable the tabletools, tableresize and liststyle plugins, which I really would rather keep.

Is there any way to do this? Scayt is useless so we moved to nanospell but it seems like a massive waste of money and effort when browsers can perform this spellchecking instead but there seems to be no way to enable it without removing a boat load of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that to get around this we had to remove the parts of the code in the tableresize and liststyle plugins that required the context menu. The plugins work fine without the menu (they even have `if` statements to not run specific parts if the context menu plugin is not present), however they still have the requirement for the context menu plugin to be present. Just remove that and you're golden.

Currently looking at a way to push these changes back into the plugins to help anyone who has the same issue in the future.